# phonegap I surrender to the camera phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I've created a new project with phonegap to take advantage of the camera, but failed to get him to let me take the picture

I've done all that was http://docs.phonegap.com/es/3.1.0/cordova_camera_camera.md.html # C% C3% A1mara

but not when I am failing, I do not get any errors. simply does nothing

my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />

        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />

        <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>
    <body>
       <button onclick="capturePhoto();">Capture Photo</button> <br>
    <button onclick="capturePhotoEdit();">Capture Editable Photo</button> <br>
    <button onclick="getPhoto(pictureSource.PHOTOLIBRARY);">From Photo Library</button><br>
    <button onclick="getPhoto(pictureSource.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM);">From Photo Album</button><br>
    <img style="display:none;width:60px;height:60px;" id="smallImage" src="" />
    <img style="display:none;" id="largeImage" src="" />


    </body>
</html>
```

and this script

```
var pictureSource;  
    var destinationType;


    document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);


    function onDeviceReady() {
        pictureSource=navigator.camera.PictureSourceType;
        destinationType=navigator.camera.DestinationType;
    }


    function onPhotoDataSuccess(imageData) {

      var smallImage = document.getElementById('smallImage');


      smallImage.style.display = 'block';



      smallImage.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
    }



    function onPhotoURISuccess(imageURI) {

      var largeImage = document.getElementById('largeImage');


      largeImage.style.display = 'block';


      largeImage.src = imageURI;
    }


    function capturePhoto() {
      // Take picture using device camera and retrieve image as base64-encoded string
      navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50,
        destinationType: destinationType.DATA_URL });
    }

    // A button will call this function
    //
    function capturePhotoEdit() {
      // Take picture using device camera, allow edit, and retrieve image as base64-encoded string
      navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { quality: 20, allowEdit: true,
        destinationType: destinationType.DATA_URL });
    }

    // A button will call this function
    //
    function getPhoto(source) {
      // Retrieve image file location from specified source
      navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, { quality: 50,
        destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI,
        sourceType: source });
    }

    // Called if something bad happens.
    //
    function onFail(message) {
      alert('Failed because: ' + message);
    }
```

I already have the permits in the config.xml in manifest.xml and I added the platform, but does not do anything. 
help. thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you installed the plugin?

You say you have no error, does it include logcat?

In your html I see no include of cordova.js and of your js file.

Comment: Yea QuickFix, i have the 2 script<script src="phonegap.js"></script> <script src="myScript.js"></script> and I've added to the command line cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.camera. and has performed flawlessly, not if you send me a complete example. not that I'm failing. alejo.go4 @ hotmail.com . Thank's